# What is definition of "active" during private beta phase?

Tags: discussion, badges

Here is the ***[BETA](https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges/16/beta)*** badge which says:

> Actively participated in the private beta.

What is "active" here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exact requirements are listed [on Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions):

> #### Beta
>
> - silver; awarded once
> - Participate actively in a site's private beta phase
>
>   - Not just 3 bronze badges anymore, but the exact requirements not disclosed to prevent users from just doing the bare minimum.
> - Not awarded on Meta sites, including Meta Stack Overflow
> - Source: [Jeff's comment to his own answer to "Why are beta badges awarded at all?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/why-are-beta-badges-awarded-at-all/#comment-44251)

Of course, for this site it's a moot point as we are no longer in private beta.